# Mobile vs cell vs phone

Tags: word-choice

I am writing some text for software that we are developing and I can't make up my mind about which word to use for "mobile phone". For example in the sentence "You need to install the app on your [blank]"

From some googling I understand that cell/cellphone is used in the US, while mobile phone may be preferred in Britain. And I know similar questions have been asked before but I have a feeling that this is a word that is actively evolving.

I'm leaning towards using just "phone", since its very clear from the context that we are not talking about landlines.

Comment: What about "smartphone"? You need to have one to downoad an app. "Portable device" may be an alternative since apps can be downloaded on tablets too.

Comment: Note that many mobile/cell phones are not "smart" phones and cannot install standard apps.

Comment: Smartphone sounds good, (assuming you don't want to specify a subset of Apple iOS, Android, Windows 8, etc. operating systems)

Comment: I find it quite remarkable that a device which has only emerged in a globalised age should already have acquired such a range of names. In America it is a *cell phone*, in Britain a *mobile*, in France *un portable*, and in the Far East (Malaysia and Singapore) they talk about their *hand phones*. The last may also be the case with the Japanese and Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

The question of "mobile" vs "cell" is one thing, but given the example sentence I think this question is maybe really trying to ask what we call the computers we use that are smaller than laptops and are primarily touch-screen devices.

In my experience there isn't a good word to describe these. Partly because they are relatively new and the terminology hasn't settled, and partly because there is a lot of overlap of categories. Phones, computers, tablets, TVs, etc, and also there are different kinds of apps: Android, iOS, Blackberry, Windows, Chrome, etc.

Some possible choices:

Download the app to ...

- your Android or iOS device
- your mobile device (assumes the reader knows not to try downloading an app to a non-supported device)
- your phone (assumes the reader knows not to try installing apps on a landline, although there are landline phones that run Android, ignores the fact that there are TVs, tablets, cameras, and even cars that run Android or iOS)
- your smartphone or tablet (slightly more specific than just phone)

You could also reword and say "Download our iOS or Android app" and let the user infer what devices it'll run on.

In short, you can just call it a phone if you expect people to run the app on their mobile phones. If you want to be clear about what kind of non-PC computers it runs on, you should be explicit. The list of non-PC computers is growing.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing!

> ... you need to install the app.

Smartphone will sounded dated when the marketing around those devices changes, and doesn't account for smart televisions like apple TV, smart watches, and things like Amazon's Echo.

There is little confusion to the user that the app won't install on a laptop, if the app isn't appropriate in that context. "Install the app" is frequently used without reference to the target device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But "Nothing" is not the solution :) The example sentence in my original question is actually displayed in a desktop browser, asking the user to pick up their phone to install a "companion" app if you will, on their phone.

Answer (score 0):

The general term for systems that run apps is “[computing] device.” The “computing” is often silent if you are already speaking in the context of computing, but if you need to introduce that context, you can say “computing device.”

Some devices are also phones, and some are not. Some of your readers might install the app you are talking about onto an iPad and it would run fine. With Android, there are many, many kinds of devices aside from phones. So “phone” is not the right term if you are specifically talking about running apps. The apps run more broadly than just on phones.

Apps are also not universal, they are platform-specific. You may want to qualify “app” with “iOS app” or “Android app” or “Windows app.”

Answer (score -2):

Kindly look at the definition of a mobile phone at AHD as below:

[https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=MOBILE&submit.x=32&submit.y=23]

Mo·bile  (mō-bēl, mōbēl′)
Share:
A city of southwest Alabama at the mouth of the Mobile River, about 61 km (38 mi) long, on the north shore of Mobile Bay, an arm of the Gulf of Mexico. Founded c. 1710, the city was held by the French, British, and Spanish until it was seized by US forces in 1813. In the Battle of Mobile Bay (August 1864), Adm. David Farragut defeated a major Confederate flotilla and secured Union control of the area.
The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition copyright ©2015 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

mo·bile  (mōbəl, -bēl′, -bīl′)
Share:
adj.
1.
a. **Capable of moving or of being moved readily from place to place: a mobile organism; a mobile missile system.**

## *b. Of or relating to wireless communication devices, such as cell phones.*

From above it shall be seen that phones can be divided to 2 classes:
[1]Mobile and [2]Immobile.
The class or the set at [1] can be further divided in to subsets.
[A] Wireless phones such as used by the Police vans etc.
[B] Cell phones which you refer.

***Conclusion and advice: "You need to install the app on any Mobile phone such as Cell phone"***

Hope your problem is solved.
Hope, you shall let me know your feed- back. Regards to all on site. I am enjoying this place.Feel great.

Comment: Three things. First, you don't need to cite all the irrelevant definitions a word has, it just clutters up your answer and makes it difficult to find the important things.

Comment: Second, in modern phone lingo, "mobile phone" and "cell phone" are equivalent. Technically, there are other kinds of phones that are mobile, such as satellite phones, but they are so rare that nobody considers them. So your example sentence of "any mobile phone such as a cell phone" is very odd-sounding because your example is a synonym of your category.

Comment: Third, if you want to be very precise, there are many cell phones which cannot install apps, and there are many devices which can install apps which are not cell phones.

Comment: I agree with 1st point you made, but humbly disagree with 2 nd and 3rd.

Comment: You...disagree that there are cell phones which can't install apps? The Nokia 301 wants a word with you. So do the Samsung Galaxy Tab S and iPad, as apparently they can't have apps either.

Comment: John Clifford has addressed point 3... re point 2, I'm curious if you can cite examples of "mobile phone" and "cell phone" not being synonyms. Besides sat phones, what other kinds of non-cellular mobile phones are there, and how many of them are common in English-speaking places?

Comment: If you went by the basic classification of phones advanced by AHD and cited by me earlier, you would clearly see that cell phone is a kind of mobile or movable phone unlike an immobile or stationery phone placed at say our residence.There should be no confusion about that I humbly feel. Thanks.